# html - Error Message: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setPosition')

Tags: javascript

I am working on a Intro to Comp pro class and our final assignment is to create a game, instead of doing a normal game like tic tac toe I decided to make a maze game where it would have you navigate a maze and if you hit the walls it would override your screen and you would be forced to go back to the start. I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction since I keep getting this error message when trying to move the ball.

```
function reset(){
     instructTxt = new Text("Hit the green to win!")
    instructTxt.setPosition(55, 35)
    instructTxt.setColor(Color.blue)
    add(instructTxt);var PADDLE_WIDTH = 80;
var PADDLE_HEIGHT = 15;
var PADDLE_OFFSET = 10;

var BALL_RADIUS = 13;

var NUM_ROWS = 8;
var BRICK_TOP_OFFSET = 10;
var BRICK_SPACING = 2;
var NUM_BRICKS_PER_ROW = 8;
var BRICK_HEIGHT = 10;
var BRICK_WIDTH = (getWidth() - (NUM_BRICKS_PER_ROW + 1) 
    * BRICK_SPACING) / NUM_BRICKS_PER_ROW;

var paddle, ball;
var vx; 
var vy = 8;

var NUM_TURNS = 3;
var turnsLeft = NUM_TURNS;
var bricksLeft = NUM_ROWS * NUM_BRICKS_PER_ROW;

var paused = true;
var DELAY = 40;
var instructTxt;
var pos;

function start(){
    pos = new Text(" ");
    pos.setPosition(15, 20)
    add(pos);
    checkObjects()
    reset()
    mouseMoveMethod(myMove)
    /*
  setupBall();
    mouseMoveMethod(myMove)
    */
}

    mouseMoveMethod(mousePos);
    var instructBotTxt = new Text("If you hit the black walls you get sent to the start!")
    instructBotTxt.setFont("15px Arial")
    instructBotTxt.setPosition(0, 430)
    instructBotTxt.setColor(Color.blue)
    add(instructBotTxt)
    drawBrick(30, 50, Color.black, 300, 10)
    drawBrick(370, 50, Color.black, 10, 350)
    drawBrick(30, 390, Color.black, 290, 10)
    drawBrick(30, 50, Color.black, 10, 340)
    drawBrick(320, 340, Color.black, 10, 60)
    drawBrick(270, 280, Color.black, 100, 10)
    drawBrick(220, 340, Color.black, 10, 60)
    drawBrick(280, 340, Color.black, 50, 10)
    drawBrick(125, 285, Color.black, 100, 10)
    drawBrick(125, 285, Color.black, 10, 65)
    drawBrick(180, 340, Color.black, 50, 10)
    drawBrick(80, 340, Color.black, 50, 10)
    drawBrick(80, 250, Color.black, 10, 90)
    drawBrick(80, 100, Color.black, 10, 100)
    drawBrick(80, 100, Color.black, 60, 10)
    drawBrick(140, 50, Color.black, 10, 60)
    drawBrick(80, 240, Color.black, 140, 10)
    drawBrick(220, 110, Color.black, 10, 140)
    drawBrick(220, 200, Color.black, 100, 10)
    drawBrick(270, 250, Color.black, 10, 40)
    drawBrick(320, 150, Color.black, 10, 100)
    drawBrick(270, 150, Color.black, 50, 10)
    drawBrick(220, 100, Color.black, 150, 10)
    drawBrick(130, 145, Color.black, 100, 10)
    drawBrick(90, 190, Color.black, 80, 10)
    drawBrick(320, 0, Color.green, 50, 60)
    drawBrick(310, 0, Color.black, 10, 50)
    drawBrick(370, 0, Color.black, 10, 50)
    drawBrick(310, 0, Color.black, 60, 10)
    
}

function mousePos(e){
    pos.setText("(" + e.getX() + "," + e.getY() + ")");
}

function myMove(event){
    var x = event.getX() - 13;
    if(x < 0) 
        x = 0;
    if(x + 26 > getWidth())
        x = getWidth() - 26;
    ball.setPosition(x, ball.getY());
    
            var y = event.getY() - 13;
    if(y < 0) 
        y = 0;
    if(y + 26 > getHeight())
        y = getHeight() - 26;
    ball.setPosition( ball.getX(),y);
}

/* ############## Functions to setup game ############## */
/*
function setupBall(){
    ball = new Circle(BALL_RADIUS);
    ball.setPosition(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
    ball.setColor(Color.red);
    add(ball);
}
*/
function drawBrick(x, y, color, width, height){
    var brick = new Rectangle(width, height);
    brick.setPosition(x, y);
    brick.setColor(color);
    add(brick);
}

function getCollidingObject(){
    var ball = new Circle(BALL_RADIUS);
    ball.setPosition(350,440);
    ball.setColor(Color.red);
    add(ball);
    
    var left = ball.getX() - ball.getRadius();
    var right = ball.getX() + ball.getRadius();
    
    var top = ball.getY() - ball.getRadius();
    var bottom = ball.getY() + ball.getRadius();
    
    var topLeft = getElementAt(left, top);
    if(topLeft) return topLeft;
    
    var topRight = getElementAt(right, top);
    if(topRight) return topRight;
    
    var bottomLeft = getElementAt(left, bottom);
    if(bottomLeft) return bottomLeft;
    
    var bottomRight = getElementAt(right, bottom);
    if(bottomRight) return bottomRight;
}

function checkObjects(){
    var elem = getCollidingObject();
    if(elem != null && elem.getColor() == Color.green){
        // You hit the end write code for that
        
            
        }else if(elem != null && elem.getColor() == Color.black){
            loss()
        }
    }
    


function loss(){
    var background = new Rectangle(getWidth(), getHeight())
    background.setColor(Color.red)
    background.setPosition(0,0)
    add(background);
    
    var lostTxt = new Text("You lost :o")
    lostTxt.setFont("30pt Arial")
    lostTxt.setPosition(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2)
    lostTxt.setColor(Color.brown)
    add(lostTxt);
    
    var resetMouse = new Rectangle(getWidth(), getHeight() - 450)
    resetMouse.setPosition(20, 430)
    resetMouse.setColor(Color.blue)
    add(resetMouse);
    
    var comeTxt= new Text("Come here to restart the game")
    comeTxt.setColor(Color.red)
    comeTxt.setPosition(50, 450)
    add(comeTxt);
}
```

Tried changing the variables into something substantial instead of a command for codehs to run, that did change the error message but now I have gained a new issue reading the set position error. Anything that can help me move the ball along is greatly appreciated.